# How to parse date and time 2020-07-13 12:02:22.952999+0700 to format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: date, datetime, flutter, timezone

I am using timezone package to get date and time in flutter and the result is here

```
2020-07-13 12:02:22.952999+0700
```

is there a way to take only `2020-07-13 12:02:22` without point and +0700

Comment: Why not just cut the first 19 characters off the string? You have a string, you want a string, doesn't need a parsing step.. note that you say you don't need the time zone, but the date is probably only meaningful without it because you're in +7.. If the data is +7 for a user on a machine in +4, hen dropping it rather than parsing it will mean the time part is wrong for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **intl** package

Use **DateFormat** class like this:

```
DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
```

if the result is String, parse it to DateTime Like this:

```
DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.parse('2020-07-13 
      12:02:22.952999+0700'));
```

Comment: Hi... thank you for your help, it works like what I want